# "Descending it" or "descending from it"?

Tags: grammar

Example:

> This explains my terror of losing him back at the cliff, and why I
>   risked my life descending (from) it.

Do I need to add **from**? Why and why not?

Comment: *descending it* does sound a bit odd though. I think someone would more likely say *descending the cliff*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say "I risked my life descending from it", you're implying that you descended the cliff until you reached the ground. Because if I go *from* somewhere, it's implied that I arrive *at* somewhere. If instead you say "I risked my life descending it", you're not hinting that you reached the bottom. Maybe you did, but maybe you changed your mind and went back up.

Answer (score 1):

As an AmE speaker, *descending it* sounds fine when referring to coming down from a cliff, and adding *from* seems unnecessary.